# How to correlate button between asp .net and KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am building an ASP .NET web application with KnockoutJS that plays music. I have the following code working to play audio from a JS array of local filepaths. I am having trouble getting ASP .NET and Knockout to "play nice".

**Here is a basic example of what I have working:**

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.audio = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            element.src = value;
            element.load();
            element.play();
        }
    }
};

//Note: only the last URL is currently active.
Urls = [
    'http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples/280.mp3',
    'http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples/289.mp3',
    'http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples/294.mp3',
    'http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/horse.ogg',
]

function vm() {
    this.myIndex = ko.observable(3);

    this.URL = ko.computed(function () {
        return Urls[this.myIndex()];
    }, this)

    this.myFunction = function()
    {
        this.myIndex();
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" data-bind="value: myIndex" />
    URL:<text type="text" name="name" data-bind="text: URL" ></text>
</form>

<audio data-bind="audio: URL" controls autoplay></audio>
```

In my application, I obviously do not want the user to have to type in the number of the song, rather they should scroll down my list and click the play button next to the song they want to play.

**There are 2 problems with this:**

1. How do I get the number of the song so it can work with Knockout?
2. How do I correlate that number with each button to update myIndex?

This is how I am currently displaying my list of songs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Urls = [];
</script>

@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (MusicStream.Models.SongViewModel song in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Song.cshtml", song);
    }
}
```

Then in the partial view I display the song's name and a play button (which is the main problem). I also add the url to the JS array.

```
    <input type="button" value="Play" data-bind="click: myFunction" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Urls.push('@Url.Content(Model.FilePath)');
    </script>
```

If it helps, here is a screenshot of part of the site. I have some other functions on the page, but they aren't related. Please disregard the numbers in parenthesis next to the song title.

[image]

I have thought about using Knockout's foreach binding to display my list of songs instead, however it seems like it would be redundant, as I would have a model in C# and JS for each song.

I have been playing with this single issue for awhile now, and have not been able to find a decent way to fix it. I am open to any other techniques that would be better/easier. Also, thanks a ton for your time!

Comment: C# model = serverside, Knockout model = clientside...This is not a code-smell to have both.  Knockout `foreach` binding is what you want I believe.

Comment: ok, I'll play with it and see if I can get it working using foreach. Is there a better way to go about adding the URLs/data from c# models to JS? I had to do the inline code because the src takes a Url.Content().

Comment: with Knockout's foreach I might be able to use $index to pass the song index along

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass to `myFunction` the url as a param, see: `data-bind="myFunction.bind($data,'@Url.Content(Model.FilePath)')"`, change to:

#### Partial:

```
<input type="button" value="Play" data-bind="click: myFunction.bind($data,'@Url.Content(Model.FilePath)')" />
```

#### ViewModel:

```
function vm() {

    this.URL = ko.observable("");

    this.myFunction = function(url)
    {
        this.URL(url);
    }
};
```

So see the snippet to an example, how to pass a param to a `click` binding function:

```js
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  this.myText = ko.observable();  
  
  this.myFunction= function(text){
      self.myText(text);
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-bind="value:  myText"/>

<input type="button" value="Play" data-bind="click: myFunction.bind($data,'url')" />
```

Comment: This all makes soo much more sense! Thanks

Comment: The special bind function on the button is giving me a parsing error I'm unsure of how to fix: missing ) after argument list; yet I'm sure all my () are correct

Comment: @EdgeDevelopers what is the html generated in browser?

Comment: Oh I actually just figured it out: click: myFunction.bind($data, '/Music/Ain't It Pretty-will.i.am.mp3') Notice the ' in the song name.

Comment: Changed it to <input type="button" value="Play" data-bind='click: myFunction.bind($data, "@Url.Content(Model.FilePath)")' /> and it works just fine